# HighCharts : Update a point when grouping data

Tags: highcharts

TL;DR: Have a lot of points, dataGrouping is on, how do I update an individual point?

I'm trying to make a HighCharts/HighStock chart that shows "per minute" averages over time. I do this by loading in a bunch of data that represents the "counts" and there is one record for every minute. Then, depending on how much chart data I have, I use the HighCharts dataGrouping with `average` approximation method to group all of the data.

Here's the kicker, I would like the most recent *minute* to update every *second* with its current count. Then, when we're on to the next minute, add a point and keep going. Typically I would do something like this to do that:

```
chart.series[0].data[99].update(newVal)
```

The problem is, `data` is empty by design when dataGrouping is on. I can see some point objects in `series.points` but updating them doesn't seem to do what I intend. I can also access and update the original data at `series.options.data` but updating it there doesn't seem to update the chart.

[Here is a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kZRCa/1/) demonstrating the problem. I have ~30 minutes of random consecutive data there and I have forced it to group in 5 minute windows. Anyone who can make an **individual point** update when I press that button gets my gratitude and a shiny green check mark next to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kZRCa/2/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var series = chart.get("S1");
    var _data = series.options.data;
    // try and make a point (ANY POINT) update
    _data[10][1] = 200;
    series.setData(_data);
});
```

Edit: forgot to mention that I also gave the series an id so it was easier to `get()` it.

Comment: I was worried about the performance of resetting the entire data set each time but I just tried it on my actual data and it seems to work pretty seamlessly. I'll let it run for a bit and maybe throw some spikes in there but it looks like this works!

Comment: I've been running a multi-series Highstock chart for months now with a large data set. I fetch new data every 15 seconds, add it to my internal storage and then use setData() to redo the chart data. It seems to handle it quite well. But every application has its own issues. Hopefully this solves it for you.

Comment: Yeah it seems to hold up pretty well, it also doesn't kill other parts of the chart like a typical re-render would (aka scrolling, zoom, everything else is preserved). Thanks again for the help